# Searching for variable between two times in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime, ssrs-2008

I have a variable date_entered which is in DateTime format. I made a temp field TIME which is just the time portion of date_entered. Im trying to search for the amount of tickets entered for each hour between 7am and 7pm. I need to get tickets for each hour increment between 7am and 7pm so tickets between 7-8,8-9,9-10 etc.. and they are to be displayed in different columns.

Right now I have:

```
=Iif((Hour(Fields!Time.Value) >= 7) AND 
     (Hour(Fields!Time.Value) < 8), Fields!TicketNbr.Value, 0)
```

However this is not getting only tickets between this hour interval and instead all tickets for that day. How can I get tickets just in that hour period? I am also using BIDS through Microsoft Visual Studio. Thanks!

Comment: As suggest by the answer below I think your problem is using 8 instead of 20.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a temp field TIME? There's a TIME datatype on SQL Server 2008 which allows you to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE CAST(YourDateField AS TIME) BETWEEN '07:00' and '19:00'
```

Comment: Well I need 12 different increments to search for tickets. Its not 7am to 7pm as a whole is 7-8,8-9,9-10 etc...

Comment: Condition your SELECT query adding a WHERE to limit your results to that time frame. 
You can use the query I posted but using your initial temp variable.